# MySQL 5.7.20 - SELECT FOUND_ROWS() returns incorrect result

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am having a strange problem with MySQL 5.7.20 when querying through JDBC using Spring JdbcTemplate.  The issue is that SELECT FOUND_ROWS() is not always returning the correct result and sometimes seems to return the result from the previous version of the query execution.  For example:

```
Query 1 - FOUND_ROWS = 0 - LIMIT query = 0
Query 2 - FOUND_ROWS = 0 - LIMIT query = 2
Query 3 - FOUND_ROWS = 2 - LIMIT query = 2
Query 4 - FOUND_ROWS = 2 - LIMIT query = 0
```

Here is the query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS questions.id, questions.question, 
   MATCH(questions.question) AGAINST('echo') as tscore,
   MATCH(answers.answer) AGAINST('echo') as ascore,
   MATCH(votes.comment) AGAINST('echo') as cscore
FROM questions 
LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.id = answers.questionId 
LEFT JOIN votes ON answers.id = votes.answerId
LEFT JOIN users ON questions.userId = users.id
WHERE 
  MATCH(questions.question) AGAINST('echo')
  OR MATCH(answers.answer) AGAINST('echo')
  OR MATCH(votes.comment) AGAINST('echo')
GROUP BY questions.question
ORDER BY (tscore + ascore + cscore) DESC
LIMIT 0,5;
```

Immediately followed by the call to:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

I initially thought this might be to do with JdbcTemplate connection pool and the allocation of a different connection for the invocation of SELECT FOUND_ROWS(), however looking at the code the same connection is allocated back based on the calling thread so I have discounted that possibility.

Any help that can be offered is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have a misunderstanding about the function of `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.  From the MySQL [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM tbl_name
WHERE id > 100
LIMIT 10;

SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

The second query with `FOUND_ROWS()` returns the number of records which *would* have been returned had `LIMIT` not been used.

So this is the proper interpretation of your results:

```
Query 1 - returns 0 - would have returned 0 without LIMIT
Query 2 - returns 0 - would have returned 2 without LIMIT
Query 3 - returns 2 - would have returned 2 without LIMIT
Query 4 - returns 2 - would have returned 0 without LIMIT **
```

** The last result seems suspicious, since removing `LIMIT` should not decrease the size of the result set.

**Edit:**

If the query 4 result is actually real, then perhaps it is possible that the `FOUND_ROWS` result for that query does correspond to another query.  You brushed aside the possibility that the connection could be the problem, but in reality you may have done this too quickly.  Most likely, your Spring application is configured to maintain a connection *pool*, i.e. some fixed number of connections with the database.  But the thing is, any thread can potentially use them, so there is no guarantee that someone could sweep in and run another query before you have a change to call `FOUND_ROWS`.

One possible fix here would be to run *both* queries, the `LIMIT` and `FOUND_ROWS` queries, within a single transaction.  This would guarantee that both queries are executed atomically.

Comment: Thanks Tim but I have not misunderstood - this is the behaviour I am looking for I want to retrieve the complete result count not bounded by limit (FOUND_ROWS >= LIMIT(query)).  Agreed that queries 1 and 3 are correct, agree that query 4 is suspect - I would also say query 2 is suspect given that the query returns 2 and FOUND_ROWS returns 0.

Comment: @user3127996 The results would only be suspect if the `FOUND_ROWS` number of rows were _smaller_ than the actual query output with the `LIMIT` statement.  In any case, I doubt that MySQL's APIs are broken and I suggest that your data/output is the problem.

Comment: I have amended the question to be clear that on some occasions the FOUND_ROWS *is* smaller.

Comment: @user3127996 Maybe I spoke too soon then.  I suggest running both queries within a single transaction to avoid the possibility of another thread issuing a query on the same connection before you have a chance to call `FOUND_ROWS`.

Comment: Yeah...apologies for doubting you.  A transaction would be my first guess on how to fix your problem.